# How to make generic PySide single shot slot

Tags: python, pyside

I'm trying to code generic single shot slot wrapper. Here is what I have now:

```
def single_shot_connect(signal, slot):
  signaled = [False]
  def single_shot_slot(*args, **kwargs):
    if signaled[0]: return
    signaled[0] = True
    signal.disconnect(single_shot_slot)
    slot(*args, **kwargs)

  signal.connect(single_shot_slot)

def foo(): pass

class Bar(QtCore.QObject): sig = QtCore.Signal([int])

bar1 = Bar()
bar1.sig.connect(foo)
bar1.sig.emit(1)  # (1)

bar2 = Bar()
single_shot_connect(bar2.sig, foo)
bar2.sig.emit(1)  # (2)
```

The problem is that code marked `(2)` isn't working because it tries to call `foo()` with one argument while `(1)` is working correctly.

How can I make `single_shot_connect()` to work?

**EDIT:** `single_shot_connect()` can be fixed for this special case as follows:

```
def single_shot_connect(signal, slot):
  signaled = [False]
  def single_shot_slot(): # Note absence of *args, **kwargs
    if signaled[0]: return
    signaled[0] = True
    signal.disconnect(single_shot_slot)
    slot() # Note absence of *args, **kwargs

  signal.connect(single_shot_slot)
```

But this isn't interesting in my case because I want `single_shot_connect()` to be generic and usable with any kind of signal and slot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Qt [guarantees](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals) that the order of slots invoked will be the order of `connect` statements, you can simply do this:

```
def single_shot_connect(signal, slot):
    def disconnect(*args, **kwargs):
        signal.disconnect(slot)
        signal.disconnect(disconnect)
    signal.connect(slot)
    signal.connect(disconnect)
```

After the `signal` is emitted, `slot` will be called. It is followed by a `disconnect` call, which removes the `slot` and itself. So they won't be called for subsequent emits.

Full usage example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore

class Foo(QtCore.QObject):
    sig = QtCore.Signal(int)

def bar():
    print 'running bar'


def single_shot_connect(signal, slot):
    def disconnect(*args, **kwargs):
        signal.disconnect(slot)
        signal.disconnect(disconnect)
    signal.connect(slot)
    signal.connect(disconnect)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    foo = Foo()
    single_shot_connect(foo.sig, bar)

    foo.sig.emit(1)
    foo.sig.emit(2)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, app.exit)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```